# How to plot live data using google line charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am  plotting a google line chart with data coming from server using a $interval call of every one second.Now i want add new data to the already plotted chart instead of redrawing the chart again....

```js
$interval(dataCall, 1000);

  function dataCall() {
  
   $http.get({x: "XYZ"}, successCallback, failureCallback);
   
   function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.res = response;   //response is like {"a":1, "b":2}
    drawBasic();    
   }
   
   function failureCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
   }
  }

  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
  
  var dataArray = [];
  
  function drawBasic() {
    
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('date', 'Timestamp');
   data.addColumn('number', 'value');
   
   var options = {
     hAxis: {
      title: 'Timestamp'
     },
     vAxis: {
      title: 'something'
     },
     tooltip: { isHtml: true },
     legend: {
      position: 'none'
     }
    };
    
   dataArray.push([new Date(), $scope.res]);
    
   data.addRows(dataArray);
   
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
   chart.draw(data, options);
          
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the chart has to be redrawn to display new data,
but you can avoid recreating the chart and options every time

recommend setup similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Timestamp');
  data.addColumn('number', 'a');
  data.addColumn('number', 'b');

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Timestamp'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'something'
    },
    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  dataCall();
  $interval(dataCall, 1000);

  function dataCall() {
    $http.get({x: "XYZ"}, successCallback, failureCallback);

    function successCallback(response) {
      data.addRow([new Date(), response.a, response.b]);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function failureCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

one second could be too short an interval to get the data and draw the chart...

Comment: Thanks, but this will squish the graph and make it unreadable after couple of mins.<br>Is it possible to tell the graph to have fixed time frame window (say to show 2 mins of time) and then scroll the graph...?

Comment: you can use options `hAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max` to control the visible range. if you want the ability to scroll, check out the [`ChartRangeFilter`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter_1)...